# What to do in Cyrodiil at low level?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

I'm not playing a lot, just enjoying the content and the exploring. I turned 10 yesterday and unlocked the pvp part of the game. I did all the tutorial stuff you can do in Cyrodiil and decided to do a scout mission ("start with a scout mission, you won't die as much in those").

This scout mission required me to go to some lumber mill deep in enemy territory (I'm Ebonheart, the mill was south-south-west of the imperial city). I died a few times trying to get there, but eventually I reached the mill. I did my scouting report and returned to turn in the quest.

This was fun for once, but the next scouting mission required me to go even further in enemy territory. I really don't wanna run around Cyrodiil as target practice and hope to be lucky enough to reach my goal without encountering some level 30+ guy.

Is there anything to do for a level 10, or is it just a waste of time? I like pvp, and I like the concept of how pvp works in TESO, but only dying is no fun at all. Are the other mission types even harder, or are they worth doing at my level?

Comment: @ヴァイシャリ Poor choice of words :D haha

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's a number of things you can do in ESO as a low-level player in Cyrodiil.

Firstly, you can participate in various forms of PvE content throughout the zone. NPCs are all level 50, but the game [does scale your stats to 50](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/163321/50582) as well, so you'll be able to fare okay. There are a number of dungeons, PvE quests, Skyshards, etc. in Cyrodiil to keep you busy, if you find you're not doing well in PvP right now.

Secondly, you can try to find a group of other players to join. There are usually groups of some sort advertising in Cyrodiil, and having other players to back you up can help even the odds in PvP, or even tip them heavily in your favor.

If you don't want to find a proper group to join, you can also try joining in on a siege. Whether defending or attacking, there will be plenty of players on each side of the conflict, and so plenty of support/buff/heal abilities being thrown around if you need them. The larger number of players also can make it less likely you'll personally be targeted, assuming your side is greater in number.

If you really do want to solo PvP in the zone, there's still a few options. The simplest is to leave for a few levels and come back; at level 15, you gain access to the weapon swap mechanic, and with it you also get a whole second bar of abilities to use. This one mechanic alone can make a huge difference in the performance of some builds. Also, in the early levels, you probably haven't got all your abilities morphed yet; holding off for a few more levels to get some of those upgraded (especially if you're going for morphs on abilities that add healing) can have a big impact.

You should look into improving your ability to sneak. If you're a Bosmer or Khajiit, or using Medium Armor, there are passive abilities in those skills which can help. Even without them, just learning to be aware of your surroundings, learning how close you can get before enemies see you, etc. are very useful in helping you get across Cyrodiil without trouble. A useful tactic is, upon entering sneak mode because there are enemies nearby, wait until you go undetected, then walk away from where you were in a somewhat random direction. Even if an enemy spotted you and heads to where they last saw you, you've since vanished, and it's generally not worth their time to hunt a lone player down.

Lastly, if all of the above isn't enough, you can try switching Campaign. Some of the campaigns can have lop-sided player populations, and if your own alliance is more populous in one campaign, that can translate into an easier experience while you get used to Cyrodiil and ESO PvP in general. You can either switch your Home Campaign, or just enter another one as a guest to get the hang of things. Just look at the little cell-phone-signal-bars icons in the list of campaigns to see how many people from each alliance are in a given campaign.

Comment: I went in around level 20ish once and the NPCs own me.

Comment: @Paralytic Try not to pull more than one at a time. I found that killing one NPC is pretty easy and two is still doable. Three becomes too much for me (still level 10 btw)

Comment: I found out for the second option it's best not to fight in PVP battle in low levels. most players who fight in battles are at veteran level. it's best to be a maximum veteran level and use armor and weapons at maximum level enchanted then you can fight. it's the only thing left after doing all those quests.